# Very slow performance from MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance

I have the following procedure:

```
drop procedure  if exists deletebatches;

create procedure deletebatches()

BEGIN
declare acount int default 0;
declare done INT default 0;
declare abatchno varchar(10);
declare abatchpart varchar(20);
declare cursor1 cursor   for select batchpart, batchno from batchestodelete;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1 ;
SET DONE = 0;
open cursor1;
readloop: loop
fetch cursor1 into abatchpart, abatchno;
if done = 1 then leave readloop;
end if;

delete from stockbatches where batch_batch = abatchno
and batch_part = abatchpart;

select curtime();
end loop readloop;

close cursor1;

end;

call deletebatches()
```

This query runs for so long that I have not had the patience to let it finish.  I cancel it after an hour or so.

I also created a query to `delete from stockbatches where batch_batch + batch_part in (select batch_batch + batch_part from batchestodelete)` and it took 1,278 seconds (over 21 minutes!).

There are only 776 records in the `batchestodelete` table and about 1 million in the `stockbatches` table which has indexes on `batch_part`, `batch_batch` and both fields combined.

Can anybody offer an explanation as to why this is taking so long for what is a relatively simple query?

---

Here are some pieces of information various people have asked from me.

Show full process list shows:

```
2614 root localhost:4785 Sleep 4786
2621 root localhost:4792 new_web_files Sleep 4789
2967 root localhost:1283 new_web_files Query 3 updating 
     delete from stockbatches where batch_batch = abatchno 
     and batch_part = abatchpart 3014 root localhost:1336 new_web_files 
     Query 0 show full processlist
```

`Show create table stockbatches` shows:

```
STOCKBATCHES CREATE TABLE stockbatches ( 
    batch_part varchar(20) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL, 
    batch_batch varchar(10) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL, 
    batch_qty decimal(18,2) default NULL, 
    batch_cond varchar(2) collate latin1_general_ci default NULL, 
    batch_release varchar(3) collate latin1_general_ci default NULL, 
    batch_curedate varchar(10) collate latin1_general_ci default NULL, 
    batch_lastmod datetime default NULL, 
    batch_lastaction varchar(1) collate latin1_general_ci default NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (batch_part,batch_batch), 
    KEY partno (batch_part), 
    KEY batchno (batch_batch), 
    KEY batchandpart (batch_part,batch_batch) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci
```

`Show create table batchestodelete` shows:

```
batchestodelete CREATE TABLE batchestodelete ( 
    batchpart varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
    batchno varchar(10) character set latin1 collate latin1_general_ci default NULL 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Welcome to DBA stackexchange, Ron. Can you provide the `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` while the stored proc is running? Also, can you give `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables involved?

Comment: Also, not part of a performance issue, but I notice you are doing `SET DONE = 0;`, but everywhere else it is 'done'.

Comment: I have just seen your later post with the delete with join. It worked brilliantly in 5 seconds. Thank you for your help, I am learning all the time. :)

Comment: Would it be possible to utilise the code you gave me from an MSSQL query to a linked MySql server such as this? `DELETE FROM OPENQUERY(ronsmysql, 'SELECT * FROM stockbatches') WHERE batch_part = @batchpart and batch_batch = @batchno` but using your version of the code. I cannot get my head around the syntax for the openquery.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using a cursor for this type of operation?

Most RDBMS are optimised for set-based operation, a cursor or a loop are iterative operations which perform row-by-row operations.

Whenever possible, you want to use declarative set-based code.

Try this:

```
DELETE sb
FROM stockbatches sb
INNER JOIN batchestodelete btd
ON sb.batch_batch = btd.batchno
AND sb.batch_part = btd.batchpart
```

Comment: Very good points, Vince, and I do prefer the set operation over a cursor. +1

Comment: The (first line) `DELETE FROM stockbatches` should be: `DELETE sb`

Comment: +1 for coming up with the `DELETE JOIN` concept first

Answer (score 1):

Just a stab in the dark at the moment, but this query throws a red flag to me:

```
delete from stockbatches where batch_batch = abatchno and batch_part = abatchpart;
```

If `abatchno` and/or `abatchpart` are ever empty (such as *might* be the case on the last iteration of the loop prior to `done=1`), your query would end up looking something like this:

```
DELETE FROM stockbatches WHERE batch_batch AND batch_part;
```

Which would likely delete a lot more than you are intending.